# How do I change Owner in httpd.cof

Tags: xampp

In opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf the User/Group is set to daemon by default. 
I want to set this to different User and Group.

When I do that phpmyadmin won't work anymore. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the /opt/lampp/temp folder. It didn't have the right permissions. Once I changed the permissions, I could change the user, restart the server and it  works again.